# Angular how to not update value in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use ngRepeat with interval pushes, but I the same model (with changing value). Is it a way to NOT update ngRepeat values when model changes?
Example:

```
$scope.example = 5;
$scope.exampleArray = [];
$scope.pushExample = function() {
    $scope.exampleArray.push($scope.example);
}
```

In the HTML just simple ngRepeat on exampleArray. Let's imagine we called *pushExample()* and now our view is:

```
5
```

Now we are changing *$scope.example* to 6 and calling *pushExample()* again. Now the view is:

```
6
6
```

But I want to receive:

```
5
6
```

How to implement it? 
**UPDATED:** 
HTML implementation:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="example in exampleArray track by $index">{{example}}</li></ul>
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve but when you push something in an array it should not erase the other items in it. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/kh9zox18/

Comment: do it on an event. something like *if (something){do}*

Comment: can you show your html implementation?

Comment: I added html implementation. @Mikey, your fiddle is wrong. I don't push simple numbers, I push model. Not 5 or 6, but $scope.example which can be 5 and, later, 6.

Comment: @delver I would not call my fiddle wrong, just not tailored to your likings ;)... That should not make any difference. Your model in the end is just a number, right? How do you change your model? I think that is the question at hand here, isn't it?

Comment: Works fine in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/kh9zox18/1/ Now working with the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a problem because you are using the same variable name `example`. You just need to change the name:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="ex in exampleArray track by $index">{{ex}}</li></ul>
```

`example` is already a variable set in your scope, so that is displaying instead of the array items.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Angular can't tell the difference between example as an object of the array and example the binding.

Comment: With a modified version of this Fiddle from @Mikey ( https://jsfiddle.net/kfLcuttL/ ) we saw the name isn't in conflict. The scope of the directive ng-repeat define a value for 'example' overriding the prototype of the ng-repeat $scope... so, it shouldn't be the only problem in your app

Answer (score 0):

Doing `$scope.exampleArray.push(angular.copy($scope.example))` to push a new reference should do the trick.

Comment: I think the post is about changing the value in the view with two-way binding  and pushing again with a button (for example). So it should be necessary to copy the value to not use the same reference in the two-way binding and in the array (if working on object of course, not on primitive)

Comment: Yes I made a fiddle that works exactly as you say, without a copy https://jsfiddle.net/kh9zox18/1/

Comment: And I've made the modification to explain my point : https://jsfiddle.net/kvk7n95o/1/

Comment: Ok, and I've modified it again to show my case. It seems angular does not the two way binding when it is not empty https://jsfiddle.net/kvk7n95o/2/. This is pretty odd, but maybe it is intentional?